# Take Picture in dialog and save to ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I currently have a dialog pop up that lets users add a title and description for a recipe that will be added to a recycler view after the "submit" button is clicked. I also want to add functionality so that the user can take a picture in this dialog, and it will be displayed in the popup as well as the recycler view once the dialog is closed. My problem right now is that I can't seem to call onActivityResult within the dialog, which means it can't reference the ImageView. When I make the ImageView global, my app crashes. I believe this has something to do with the fact that the ImageView in the dialog is dismissed once the camera is open, and therefore the ImageView object is null?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.SimpleItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<NoteModel> arrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton actionButton;
    DatabaseHelper database_helper;

    NotesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        actionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);

        database_helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        displayNotes();

        actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    //display notes list
    public void displayNotes() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(database_helper.getNotes());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new NotesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //display dialog
    public void showDialog() {
        final EditText title, des;

        Button submit;
        Button takepicture;
        ImageView imageView;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        params.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();

        title = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
        des = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
        submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        takepicture = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    100);
        }


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (title.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    title.setError("Please Enter Title");
                } else if (des.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    des.setError("Please Enter Description");
                } else {
                    database_helper.addNotes(title.getText().toString(), des.getText().toString());
                    dialog.cancel();
                    displayNotes();
                }
            }
        });
        takepicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }

        });
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == 100) {
                Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(captureImage);
            }
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your activity is killed when the Camera app comes to top. If the Camera app closes your activity is recreated. Not only imageView==null but also your dialog has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.kerols.myapplication1q;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.SimpleItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //display notes list
    ArrayList<NoteModel> arrayList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton actionButton;
    DatabaseHelper database_helper;
    NotesAdapter adapter;
    /////


    //display dialog
    EditText title, des;
    Button submit;
    Button takepicture;
    ImageView imageView;
    /////


    public MainActivity() {
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    100);
        }
                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        actionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);

        database_helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        displayNotes();

        actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    //display notes list
    public void displayNotes() {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(database_helper.getNotes());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new NotesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //display dialog
    public void showDialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        params.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();

        title = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
        des = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.description);
        submit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        takepicture = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    100);
        }


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (title.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    title.setError("Please Enter Title");
                } else if (des.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    des.setError("Please Enter Description");
                } else {
                    database_helper.addNotes(title.getText().toString(), des.getText().toString());
                    dialog.cancel();
                    displayNotes();
                }
            }
        });
        takepicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(captureImage);

            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you

```
if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (data != null) {
        Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(captureImage);

    }
}
```